# React Native Maps Price

Tags: react-native, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2, react-native-maps

I am making an app using react native and I want to implement a map using react-native-maps library MapView.

The application will use the map to display markers on it for users using signals to share it with multiple users.

I don't want a dynamic map or something just tiles.

I don't understand how pricing works, I read some people say it's free others say it's not.

I would like some explanation on how MapView works in real application with a large number of users.

```
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, Button } from "react-native";
import MapView, {
  PROVIDER_GOOGLE,
  MAP_TYPES,
  PROVIDER_DEFAULT,
  UrlTile,
  Marker,
} from "react-native-maps";
import React from "react";

export default function Home({ navigation }) {
  let location = {
    latitude: 23.259933,
    longitude: 77.412613,
    latitudeDelta: 0.009,
    longitudeDelta: 0.009,
  };

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <View style={styles.myMap}>
        {/* <MapView
          style={StyleSheet.absoluteFillObject}
          provider={PROVIDER_GOOGLE}
          mapType="hybrid"
          region={location}
        /> */}
        <MapView
          region={location}
          provider={null}
          mapType={MAP_TYPES.HYBRID}
          rotateEnabled={false}
          style={{ flex: 1 }}
          style={styles.map}
          showsUserLocation
        >
          {/* <UrlTile
            urlTemplate="http://a.tile.openstreetmap.de/tiles/osmde/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
            maximumZ={19}
          /> */}
          <Marker
            title="Home"
            coordinate={{
              latitude: location.latitude,
              longitude: location.longitude,
            }}
          />
        </MapView>
      </View>
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: "#ffd",
    alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent: "center",
  },
  myMap: {
    flex: 2,
    backgroundColor: "white",
    width: "100%",
    marginTop: 30,
    marginBottom: 30,
  },
  map: {
    width: "100%",
    height: "100%",
  },

});
```

Answer (score 2):

Open street map managed host is free and support only iOS with `react-native-maps`, It's not recommended for large scale app, when happen, you need to host map tiles on your own servers,

Google maps are cross-platform and performant but let's examine their pricing.

Google map bill client per request, in React Native context, when a user navigates to screen with a map inside, Map SDK query google server and render the map, this count as a single request.

Rendering markers or other UI elements have no impact on map requests and Google will not bill for that.

Zoom and pan are not counted as requests and will not impact your billing invoice.

Technically, you can be billed for a single server request and a user continues to use the map-based features.

If you're building an uber-like app with turn-to-turn navigation with continuous server requests, pricing will be huge.

Comment: Does ``` <MapView></MapView>```  considered MAP SDK query? it's just plain tiles without any interactable icons.
Actually, I have a map rendered in my app right now without adding any API key.

Comment: Are you using Expo or React Native CLI

Comment: I am using Expo

Comment: I don't need to use any kind of API, I just want a map with plain tiles with the ability to put markers on it.

Comment: In development, you don't need  Google Map API key with Expo but in production build, it's required.

Comment: Ok thank you so much, I get it now. 
By the way, do you have any suggestion that would fit with my requirements?
I can't find an up to date library for OpenStreetMap.
I tried react-native-webview-leaflet but it's not working with react 17.0.1

Comment: On large scale it will cost a lot

Comment: Use Google Map on Android and enable Apple Map on iOS. Apple map is partially free as it's part of developer annually account fees

Comment: I am sorry for that but what is Google Map on Screen.

Comment: It was a typo  mistake I corrected it.

Comment: Ok I will look into it, Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: Don't stress out with scalability too much, If Google map is too expensive, at that point your app will surpasses free OpenStreetMap tile server requests. You will need to host your map tiles dataset and build your own map client side map map view.

Comment: You still have other option https://github.com/react-native-mapbox-gl/maps for cheap option